# About leftBarButtonItem doesn't appear programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add a `leftBarButtonItem` in my View Controller's navigation bar programmatically (This View Controller is embedded in a Navigation Controller). I implement this code in `viewDidLoad`

```
let backButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
backButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "BackButton.png"), for: .normal)
backButton.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
backButton.setTitleColor(backButton.tintColor, for: .normal)
backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.backAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
```

I run the test, but the backButton does not appear in the view controller at all. I am thinking, Should I put this piece code in the navigation controller with the View Controller is embedded in?
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Back")!, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.actionBack))
```

Comment: It works now, but I still want to know how come my approach was not working?

Comment: Give a frame to your custom button

Comment: Does it mean if I choose custom which is not compatible with my following setting?

Comment: You are adding custom view to the Bar button so you don't need to choose custom type for UIButton just set a frame there.

Comment: @Nan You must accept this answer. If it's solved your problem.